# How to pass parameters to callback?

Tags: c#, wpf

Code callback in C#:

```
private void CallbackVisibleButton(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    AsynchronousVisibleButtonDelegate asyncDeleg = (AsynchronousVisibleButtonDelegate)ar.AsyncState;
    b.Visibility = asyncDeleg.EndInvoke(ar);// b - not see!
}
private delegate Visibility AsynchronousVisibleButtonDelegate(Button b);
private Visibility AsynchronousVisibleButton(Button b)
{
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    return Visibility.Visible;
}
```

and createted  (b is Button, 5 seconds after the button should be visible):

```
AsynchronousVisibleButtonDelegate asyncDeleg = new AsynchronousVisibleButtonDelegate(AsynchronousVisibleButton);
AsyncCallback callback = new AsyncCallback(CallbackVisibleButton);
asyncDeleg.BeginInvoke(b, callback, asyncDeleg);
```

problem: CallbackVisibleButton - does not see the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the code below will solve your problem.  Remove CallBackVisib... method and do as follows in your main code:

```
        AsynchronousVisibleButtonDelegate asyncDeleg = new AsynchronousVisibleButtonDelegate(AsynchronousVisibleButton);
        AsyncCallback callback = new AsyncCallback(p =>
                                                       {
                                                           var anotherState =
                                                               p.AsyncState as AsynchronousVisibleButtonDelegate;
                                                           b.Visible = anotherState.EndInvoke(p);
                                                       });
        asyncDeleg.BeginInvoke(b, callback, asyncDeleg);
```

Answer (score 1):

use the third parameter of the `BeginInvoke` to send extra information. then you can get it through the `IAsyncResult.AsyncState` property.

here is an example: http://progtutorials.tripod.com/C_Sharp.htm